# Python mysql.connector error while inserting boolean into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

In the code below, I am trying to insert a boolean value in Network table, where the status field is declared as boolean.

```
import urllib2
import mysql.connector as conn
import MySQLdb
import logging

class getData:

    @staticmethod   
    def checkNetwork():
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com', timeout = 2)
            return True
        except urllib2.URLError as err:
            return False

    @staticmethod
    def connectDB():
        db = conn.connect(host='****', user='****', passwd='****', db='*******')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        return db,cursor

    @staticmethod
    def insertNData(data):
        print type(data)
        db,cursor = getData.connectDB()
        sql_Query = "INSERT INTO Network(status) VALUES(%s);"
        try:
            result= cursor.execute(sql_Query,data)
            db.commit()
            logging.warn("%s", result)
            logging.info("Success")
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            logging.warn("Failed")
        finally:
            db.close()
        return True


netStat = getData.checkNetwork()

getData.insertNData(netStat)
```

When I run the code, I get the below error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

I tried searching on google to find some solution and also changed a few things to test but still the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is error in this line:

```
sql_Query = "INSERT INTO Network(status) VALUES(%s);"
```

You are not passing the value correctly. You created a placeholder but did not fill it.

Use:
for python3.6 and above:

```
sql_Query = f"INSERT INTO Network(status) VALUES({data});"
```

for python 2 and 3:

```
sql_Query = "INSERT INTO Network(status) VALUES({});".format(data)
```

or

```
sql_Query = "INSERT INTO Network(status) VALUES(%s);" %(data)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Is it just for boolean we need to do it? Since I have another function where I am inserting a list into the database using `(%s, %s...)` and that seems to work completely fine. I am new to Python so want to know the correct way.

Comment: for every placeholder you must pass equivalent variable. You must be passing that in your other function , that's why it's working. I would recommend you to use format or f-string(python3.6) as it is easy to use and is new standard.

Comment: This way is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should pass the values as the second parameter so that the library will pass them in properly.